# How to access the OneSignal PlayerId within flutter app?

Tags: flutter, onesignal

The App is working and receives notifications. Unfortunately, to understand the PlayerId is needed to go to Onesignal dashboard and then Subscription to find the last device conected.

How to access the variables:

```
OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.id;
OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.token;
```

as described in https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/mobile-sdk ?

The function

```
OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.addObserver((state) async {
   to access ...

   OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.optedIn;
   OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.id;
   OneSignal.User.pushSubscription.token;
   state.current.jsonRepresentation();
   ...
}
```

seems to work only once in device lifetime.
Thank you